# Numerical linear algebra problem (QR decomposition)

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

**Problem**: Given the QR-decomposition of a rectangular matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, where $m > n > 1$, find the QR-decomposition of a matrix $A_k \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times (n - 1)}$,
which is matrix $A$ with its $k$-th column removed. The procedure may use $\mathcal{O}(m \cdot (n - k))$ elementary operations ($+$, $-$, $\cdot$, $/$, $\sqrt{}$ etc.)

I think that this could easily be done with Givens rotations, but that would use too many operations because you would have to calculate the new matrix $Q^{(1)}$ by using all those Givens rotations on the old matrix $Q$. The last part of the exercise left me stumped and I have no idea how to continue. This exercise is from an old exam, so it's not homework or whatever. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What was your estimate for how many operations the Givens approach would take? I am pretty sure it's the right approach.

Comment: **Hint:** Note that $Q^\top A_k$ is not quite upper triangular, but it is [upper-Hessenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix), with only $n-k$ entries that need to be "zeroed out".